# Find and Replace Multiple Lines in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

I have a document that has a product length | product name | and product price

I have used this code I found online to replace the product price:

```
Sub Multi_FindReplaceALL_pvc_replace_new()
'PURPOSE: Find & Replace a list of text/values throughout entire workbook
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim x As Long

fndList = Array("2 ft", "PVC", "390")
rplcList = Array("2 ft", "PVC", "290")

'Loop through each item in Array lists
 For x = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)
'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
  For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sht.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(x), Replacement:=rplcList(x), _
      LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
      SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
  Next sht

  Next x

End Sub
```

The issue I am having is this VB script is replacing the product name Acrylic's pricing as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I can also supply any additional information if needed.

Image Link of Doc: http://prntscr.com/h1votx

Comment: Please explain how do you expect your code works.

Comment: What does the pricing have to do with the code you posted? How would we/you know what the updated pricing should be?

Comment: I want to change the 2 ft PVC price of 390 to 290 across all 2 ft PVC products.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It's a shopify exported product CSV document.

Comment: That makes sense - what it looks like you're currently doing is replace "2 ft" with "2 ft", "PVC" with "PVC" and "390" with "290" - so the only change you're seeing is that **all** "390" values change to "290".

Comment: Document screenshot: http://prntscr.com/h1votx

Comment: Yes, Darren - I need it to only replace the "pvc" product 2 ft pricing, and so on for the various sizes without having to edit each of these rows if possible.

Comment: prntscr.com..... Access denied for me, but so are the SO images.  Update your original question with the image and someone should be able to help you (I can't as I can't see the image).

Comment: So I basically need to to be strict when I want to change the price of each product size line item.  How can I do this?  I feel like I am really close.

Answer (score 0):

Do you only have 1 sheet? This code will work with the sheet in the print screen, however it is hard coded to the current columns that the values fall into. It can be relaxed a bit if you need it to work for different values or different columns.

```
Sub Multi_FindReplaceALL_pvc_replace_new()
'PURPOSE: Find & Replace a list of text/values throughout entire workbook
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Dim lastRow As Integer

'get the last row in the sheet
With ActiveSheet
  lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'Loop through each row in the sheet
 For i = 1 To lastRow
'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook
    If Cells(i, 9).Value = "2 ft" And Cells(i, 11).Value = "PVC" Then
        Cells(i, 20).Value = "290"
    End If
  Next i

End Sub
```

Basically your code before was just running through the entire sheet and changing all the values if they were in that array. This function goes row by row and specifically compares the columns that contain your values

Comment: of course the easier way would be to add a filter to the columns, and then filter by option1 and option2 and then you can just edit all the rows at the same time

Comment: Hi Kudu2 - I tried that code and for some reason I couldn't get it to replace the PVC price from 390 to 290 in the 2 ft line.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought your option1 and option2 were in columns b and d. I've updated the code for the proper columns. But like i said, if you add a filter to your column names, it's a lot easier to deal with large amounts of data. see https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/filtering-data/1/